# Function optimized for compile-time constant

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

Suppose that I have a vector length calculation function, which has an additional `inc` parameter (this tells the distance between neighboring elements). A simple implementation would be:

```
float calcLength(const float *v, int size, int inc) {
    float l = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<size*inc; i += inc) {
        l += v[i]*v[i];
    }
    return sqrt(l);
}
```

Now, `calcLength` can be called with two kind of `inc` parameters: when `inc` is known at compile-time, and when it is not. I'd like to have an optimized `calcLength` version for common compile-time values of `inc` (like 1).

So, I'd have something like this:

```
template <int C>
struct Constant {
    static constexpr int value() {
        return C;
    }
};

struct Var {
    int v;

    constexpr Var(int p_v) : v(p_v) { }

    constexpr int value() const {
        return v;
    }
};

template <typename INC>
float calcLength(const float *v, int size, INC inc) {
        float l = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<size*inc.value(); i += inc.value()) {
            l += v[i]*v[i];
        }
        return sqrt(l);
    }
}
```

So, this can be used:

```
calcLength(v, size, Constant<1>()); // inc is a compile-time constant 1 here, calcLength can be vectorized
```

or

```
int inc = <some_value>;
calcLength(v, size, Var(inc)); // inc is a non-compile-time constant here, less possibilities of compiler optimization
```

My question is, would it be possible somehow to keep the original interface, and put `Constant`/`Var` in automatically, depending on the type (compile-time constant or not) of `inc`?

```
calcLength(v, size, 1); // this should end up calcLength(v, size, Constant<1>());
calcLength(v, size, inc); // this should end up calcLength(v, size, Var(int));
```

Note: this is a simple example. In my actual problem, I have several functions like `calcLength`, and they are large, I don't want the compiler to inline them.

---

Note2: I'm open to different approaches as well. Basically, I'd like to have a solution, which fulfills these:

- the algorithm is specified once (most likely in a template function)
- if I specify `1` as `inc`, a special function instantiated, and the code most likely gets vectorized
- if `inc` is not a compile-time constant, a general function is called
- otherwise (non-1 compile-time constant): doesn't matter which function is called

Comment: AFAIK, unless the entire function is `constexpr` passing a compile time constant doesn't gain you anything.  One thing you could do though is make the constant a non type template parameter.  Then the value will be known at compile time and the compiler can optimize accordingly.

Comment: @NathanOliver: as far as I see, this is what I'm doing in the question. With one difference:  to allow both kind of `inc`, it has a type template parameter. But the outcome is the same.

Comment: Are you looking for [if constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) ?

Comment: I mean a function like `template <std::size_t inc>
float calcLength(const float *v, int size) { use inc here as a compile time value }`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: your suggestion has the same outcome as my solution, if `Constant<X>` used as `inc`.

Comment: Do you have any benchmarks conforming you conjuncture about "better optimizations"? I can image hypothetical cases if inc % 8 == 0 or inc % 16 ==0, but would not be sure it can vectorized much better.

Comment: @Dmitry: in my case, if `inc` is known at compile-time, it will be 1 99% of the time. And of course, it can be optimized much better. It has a huge speed difference.

Comment: @geza I think "do you have benchmarks" means "post your benchmark so I can verify that my solution works".

Comment: @anatolyg: I have benchmarks, but not for this simple case. But actually, this question doesn't need a benchmark. It's more of a language question. Basically, I'd like to have a function, which can be automatically compiled for compile-time constant. My code works, but I dislike the manual `Constant`/`Var` specification. I'd like this to be automatic.

Comment: So you have evidence that this approach is actually better on your architecture than just making the function inline and letting the optimizer worry about it? That would be good to explain or at least mention in the question.

Comment: @aschepler: I mentioned in the question that I have several functions, and they are huge. I'm absolutely sure that the compiler won't inline them because of their size. I'd need to use some `forceinline` feature. But I don't want to, because compiled code-size will be much bigger. It would be a mistake to inline these functions on any current architecture.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I don't know how I can use `if constexpr` in my problem, so probably not.

Comment: But if `inc` isn't a compile-time constant but with value `1`, which function should be called? It's OK, for you, if it's called the `Constant<1>` version?

Comment: @max66: basically it's never the case. But I think I see why you ask this: I could add a little inline wrapper function, which checks for 1. I don't really like this solution, because it adds an unnecessary if for the not-compile-time constant case. If that's the only solution, I'll keep using `Constant`/`Var`.

Comment: [std::integral_constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant), but It doesn't seem to have been effective: https://godbolt.org/z/YuSK0L

Comment: Now that I enabled optimizations, both versions got calculated at compile time: https://godbolt.org/z/-s1xNS

Comment: If you don't mind portability too much, `__builtin_constant_p` is a great tool for this kind of optimization.

Comment: If you are using GCC, as @MarcGlisse suggested,  [__builtin_constant_p](https://godbolt.org/z/uuPutd) would work but if conditions are still runtime one in this example...

Answer (score 2):

If the goal here is simply to optimize, rather than enable use in a compile-time context, you can give the compiler hints about your intent:

```
static float calcLength_inner(const float *v, int size, int inc) {
    float l = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<size*inc; i += inc) {
        l += v[i]*v[i];
    }
    return sqrt(l);
}

float calcLength(const float *v, int size, int inc) {
    if (inc == 1) {
        return calcLength_inner(v, size, inc);  // compiler knows inc == 1 here, and will optimize
    }
    else {
        return calcLength_inner(v, size, inc);
    }
}
```

[From godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/p1Q6GC), you can see that `calcLength_inner` has been instantiated twice, both with and without the constant propagation.

This is a C trick (and is used extensively inside numpy), but you can write a simple wrapper to make it easier to use in c++:

```
// give the compiler a hint that it can optimize `f` with knowledge of `cond`
template<typename Func>
auto optimize_for(bool cond, Func&& f) {
    if (cond) {
        return std::forward<Func>(f)();
    }
    else {
        return std::forward<Func>(f)();
    }
}

float calcLength(const float *v, int size, int inc) {
    return optimize_for(inc == 1, [&]{
        float l = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<size*inc; i += inc) {
            l += v[i]*v[i];
        }
        return sqrt(l);
    });
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the missing return, fixed

Comment: Godbolt link added

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not provide a way to detect whether a supplied function parameter is a constant expression or not, so you cannot automatically differentiate between supplied literals and runtime values.

If the parameter *must* be a function parameter, and you're not willing to change the way it is called in the two cases, then the only lever you have here is the type of the parameter: your suggestions for `Constant<1>()` vs `Var(inc)` are pretty good in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Trust you compiler (aka do nothing)

Can compilers can do what you want without you lifting a finger (well, you need to enable optimized builds, but that goes without saying).

Compilers can create what are called "function clones", which do what you want. A clone function is a copy of a function used for constant propagation, aka the resulting assembly of a function called with constant arguments. I found little documentation about this feature, so it's up to you if you want to rely on it.

The compiler can inline this function altogether, potentially making your problem a non-problem (you can help it by defining it inline in a header, using lto and/or using compiler specific attributes like `__attribute__((always_inline))`)

Now, I am not preaching to let the compiler do its job. Although the compiler optimizations are amazing these times and the rule of thumb is to trust the optimizer, there are situation where you need to manually intervene. I am just saying to be aware of and to take it into consideration. Oh, and as always **measure, measure, measure** when it comes to performance, don't use your "I feel here I need to optimize" gut.

## Option 2: Two overloads

```
float calcLength(const float *v, int size, int inc) {
    float l = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<size*inc; i += inc) {
        l += v[i]*v[i];
    }
    return sqrt(l);
}

template <int Inc>
float calcLength(const float *v, int size) {
    float l = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<size*inc; i += inc) {
        l += v[i]*v[i];
    }
    return sqrt(l);
}
```

The disadvantage here is code duplication, ofc. Also little care need to be taken at the call site:

```
calcLength(v, size, inc); // ok
calcLength<1>(v, size);   // ok
calcLength(v, size, 1);   // nope
```

## Option 3: Your version

Your version is ok.

Comment: @geza awesome proposal, but it looks it stills needs some considerable amount of work.